# Misredirect with validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have two different routes:

```
Route::post('contact', 'PublicController@postContact');
Route::post('inquiry', [ 'as' => 'inquiry', 'uses' => 'PublicController@postInquiry']);
```

and their methods:

```
    public function postContact(Request $request){ 

    $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
    if (strlen($token) >0 ) {
        $this->validate($request, [
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',          
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'min:3',
        'message' => 'min:10']);

    $data = array(
        'fname' => $request->fname,
        'lname' => $request->lname,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('rahunn3@gmail.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was sent sucessfully!');

    return redirect('/contact');
    }
}
```

and:

```
    public function postInquiry(Request $request){
    $token = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
    if (strlen($token) >0 ){
        $this->validate($request, [
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',            
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'min:3',
        'message' => 'min:10']);
    $data = array(
        'fname' => $request->fname,
        'lname' => $request->lname,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'country' => $request->country,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

    Mail::send('emails.inquiry', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('rahunn3@gmail.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was sent sucessfully!');          

        return view('public.pages.thankyou');   
    }           
}
```

the trouble i'm having is the second method is not working as it should be.The inquiry form is in view(single.blade.php). After sumbitting the form user should be redirected to view(thankyou.blade.php) view but it is redirecting to view(single.blade.php) without sending email and doesn't show any errors.

If I remove the validation part:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'fname' => 'required',
    'lname' => 'required',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'country' => 'required',            
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'subject' => 'min:3',
    'message' => 'min:10'
]);
```

from the second method postInquiry it works perfectly(sends email and redirects do thankyou.blade.php)

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting because your validation is failing.

Add the following code to the top of your single.blade.php file and it will tell you why the validation is failing

```
@if($errors->has())
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
  <div>{{ $error }}</div>
 @endforeach
@endif
```

See here for more information : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors